# Truncate the method in java

Tags: java, silktest

I have the following code:

```
public class Search {

    private Desktop desktop = new Desktop();

    @Before
    public void baseState() {
        BrowserBaseState baseState = new BrowserBaseState("silk4j.settings");
        baseState.execute(desktop);

    }

    @Test
    public void searchNames() {
        desktop.<BrowserApplication>find("//BrowserApplication").<BrowserWindow>find("//BrowserWindow").<DomButton>find("//INPUT[@id='edit-submit']").select();

    }

}
```

I was able to truncate the Test method to this:

```
public class Search {

    private Desktop desktop = new Desktop();
    BrowserApplication app;


    @Before
    public void baseState() {
        BrowserBaseState baseState = new BrowserBaseState("silk4j.settings");
        app = baseState.execute(desktop);

    }

    @Test
    public void searchNames() {
        app.<BrowserWindow>find("//BrowserWindow").<DomButton>find("//INPUT[@id='edit-submit']").select();

}
```

How do I truncate the method even further? I would like to be able to use something like this:

```
win.<DomButton>find("//INPUT[@id='edit-submit']").select();
```

instead of this chunky long:

```
desktop.<BrowserApplication>find("//BrowserApplication").<BrowserWindow>find("//BrowserWindow").<DomButton>find("//INPUT[@id='edit-submit']").select();
```

Please paste the whole class in your response?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835943/truncate-the-reference-to-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Search {

    private Desktop desktop = new Desktop();
    BrowserWindow win;

    @Before
    public void baseState() {
        BrowserBaseState baseState = new BrowserBaseState("silk4j.settings");
        win = baseState.execute(desktop).find("//BrowserWindow");
    }

    @Test
    public void searchNames() {
        win.<DomButton>find("//INPUT[@id='edit-submit']").select();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though your code works, it can be truncated even further: win = baseState.execute(desktop).<BrowserWindow>find("//BrowserWindow"); app could be removed completely. Would you like to modify your post?